# mysql_fetch_array() timing out

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to query a database, but it seems to just load for an age and not do anything. It's a simple query and shouldnt take longer than a millisecond.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array(getWallPosts($userid)))
{
}
```

Now when I replace this code with:

```
echo mysql_num_rows(getWallPosts($userid));
```

It just displays '1' in fact there's only one record in the DB and it's just a simple SELECT statement.

Here's the getWallPosts function:

```
function getWallPosts($userid, $limit = "10")
{
    $result = dbquery("SELECT * FROM commentpost 
                           WHERE userID = ".$userid." 
                           ORDER BY commentPostID DESC LIMIT 0, ".$limit);
    return $result;
}
```

Also, when I put the SQL string that it's executing into MySQL's query browser. It takes no time at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: change `$result = dbquery("SELECT * FROM commentpost 
                               WHERE userID = ".$userid." 
                               ORDER BY commentPostID DESC LIMIT 0, ".$limit);` to `$result = dbquery("SELECT * FROM commentpost WHERE userID = '".$userid."' 
                               ORDER BY commentPostID DESC LIMIT 0, ".$limit);` otherwise you may suffer SQL-injection attacks (depending on where $userid came from, also note that if $limit comes from outside, there's NO WAY to protect against SQL-injection. If it's from inside you're safe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be looping indefinitely because you're retrieving a new set (one record) of data each time.

```
$result = getWallPosts($userid);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    //printf($row[0]);  
}
```

Comment: +1.  Try: `$r = getWallPosts($userid); while($row = mysql_fetch_array($r)) {}`

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the data once and loop through it. Your code is getting the data, running the loop and then getting the data again.

Try:

```
$posts = getWallPosts($userid);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($posts))
{
  //Code to execute
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its an infinite loop.  The expression in the while always executes so it will always be true.

Answer (score 0):

You're returning a new result set each time the while statement executes. You should call `getWallPosts` first, assign it to $results, and then loop over it.